# How to set carousel in the middle of the screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this in carousel.css file (bootstrap), I set width of the image to 900px, but I want to have this image in the middle of the screen, how to do it? (I tried to edit left variable, but nothing happened, and I want it not fixed, something like `<center></center>`)

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

index.html:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#7a7a7a/text:blabla" alt="First slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>aaa</h1>
                    <p>xxxx</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to center horizontally you can do `margin: 0 auto;` and get rid of your absolute positioning. If you want to center vertically and horizontally you can do

```
.carousel-inner{
position: relative;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `#myCarousel` div's width to `900px` too and `margin: 0 auto`.